# java annotation enum array default value

Tags: java, enums, annotations

I want to write an annotation that hast a EnumArray Field. Default value should be all values of the Enum. This code works but I don't want to specify every enum manually.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CommonScope
{
    ECountry[] countries() default {ECountry.AT, ECountry.DE};

}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
ECountry[] countries() default ECountry.values();
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: you can use  EnumSet.allOf(ECountry.class)

Comment: @KennethClark - How - I can't seem to make that work. n'or does `EnumSet.allOf(A.class).toArray()`.

Comment: Hm does not work. I get the same error when I Use values() ... Eclipse tells me "The value for annotation attribute CommonScope.countries must be an enum constant expression"

Comment: you tried `public static ECountry[] COUNTRY = (EStatus[]) EnumSet.allOf(ECountry.class).toArray();`

Comment: This will add all the values , not sure is that's what you expected , if you want specific values .. Like just two countries but the enum contains 10 you will have to add a little more logic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible, annotation declaration is very limited. You can not call any methods or use properties, you can only use *compile time constant expressions*, that are known at compile time by the compiler.

As a workaround, you could add a special enum value like `Countries.ALL_COUNTRIES` if that makes sense for your application.